# Firewall security issue in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I'm using symfony2 And having a little bit problem about Authentication and access control in symfony firewall.

This is my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        test\UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    administrators:
        entity: { class: UserBundle:User, property: email }

firewalls:

    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/login$
        anonymous:  ~
        security: true

    admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/cp|/(cp/.*|login_check)
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  _login
            check_path:  login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY|ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(booking/hotelsearchresult), roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The thing is in this site, there is no /admin path or a spesefic path for admin.
admin is defined by the Role in each page and the contetnt of the pages is diffrent acording to user types. (That's bad I know).

It means I must have all users access to all pages exept some and if they login, they get diffrent type of data.

but I have the following error:

When I log in, and send the user to another path ( which is not defiend as a secured path) it does not show any creditential information?!!!

what should I do to have and access the data with this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you wrote: If your path is not under firewall, credential information aren't available there because firewall won't cover them.

In your specific case, you will have access to credential information **only** on routes that start with `/cp`. What you **probably** want to do is define firewall pattern as `^/`. So that your firewall covers **all** paths on your website, and then use `access_control` or whatever method you use to check access permissions for specific page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what role a specific user has with the following code in your controllers:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // show different content to admin users
    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        // ... load admin content here
    }

    // ... load other regular content here
}
```